# How to get activity_main.xml buttons on top of other content such as sprites

Tags: java, android-studio

I have two moving images in a program

I just discovered activity_main.xml and wanted to use those buttons.

In my program I created a gameview printing to the canvcas, it prints two moving images by updating them and changing position in my GameView. Pretty standard.

```
setContentView(new GameView(this));
```

To call the buttons I am supposed to use below call, but it conflicts with the other content view.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

I want to place the buttons ontop of my movin images.
Is that possible with buttons created in activity main?

**To shorten it down**

1. Is it possible to combine moving images with activity_main.xml?
2. How do I call activity main as a transparent layer with buttons ontop my moving images.

Answer (score 0):

So the newbie coder found the solution!! = That is me!

```
LayoutInflater inflater = /*LayoutInflater.from(YourActivity.this); // or */(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View viewMyLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
```

in my case

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 

getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View viewMyLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
```

I added that in

```
    gameButtons.setLayoutParams(parameters);
    gameButtons.addView(viewMyLayout); // <---- HERE!!

    game.addView(gameView);
    game.addView(gameButtons);

    setContentView(game);
```

And now it works!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71753660/wrapping-an-xml-file-in-a-relativelayout-setcontentviewr-layout-activity-main/71763190#71763190