# Wrapping an xml File in a RelativeLayout setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); --> new RelativeLayout(this);

Tags: java, android-studio, android-relativelayout

I want to wrap activity_xml in a RelativeLayout, I tried several ways, bit non is working. Is it possible?
Mine is called gameButtons --> gameButtons.addView(#problem how to add activity_xml here#);

```
public class Game extends AppCompatActivity {

    GamePanel gameView; // The class extending SurfaceView
    FrameLayout game; // Holder between SurfaceView and RelativeLayout
    RelativeLayout gameButtons; // Where I add the buttons
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Creating Layout Objects
        gameView = new GamePanel(this);
        game = new FrameLayout(this);
        gameButtons = new RelativeLayout(this);
        ContentView activityView = ContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams activityMain = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        //Define the layout parameter for whatever we want to wrap both width and heigth
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams parameters = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        // Matching with the content we want to add

        gameButtons.setLayoutParams(parameters);
        gameButtons.addView(activityView); << ---- PROBLEM !!


        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(new GamePanel(this));
    }
}
```

I expected the posibility to both show buttons from activity_main and other content under via the RelativeLayout..

I need to use the intent functions for buttons = the buttons in activity_xml

I tried thesegameButtons.addView(activity_xml);

*gameButtons.addView(ContentView(R.layout.activity_main));

*gameButtons.addView(R.layout.activity_main);

*gameButtons.addView(activityView);

*// where I played with ContentView activityView = ContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Answer (score 0):

So the newbie coder found the solution!! = That is me!

```
LayoutInflater inflater = /*LayoutInflater.from(YourActivity.this); // or */(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View viewMyLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
```

in my case

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 

getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View viewMyLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
```

I added that in

```
gameButtons.setLayoutParams(parameters);

gameButtons.addView(viewMyLayout); // <---- HERE!!
    
game.addView(gameView);
game.addView(gameButtons);
    
setContentView(game);
```

And now it works!